# Any font pairing sites outside of Google?

Tags: web-fonts, google, font-pairing

I love how Google fonts allows you to pair fonts for great eye candy when designing but after time I have gotten tired of just seeing what Google suggests.  I wanted to know if anyone has scene any other sites that have a wider spectrum of font pairing other than Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know of any type-pairing sites specifically but I will list some resources I have come across on the subject as well as places you could ask typographers directly about the topic.

Check Smashing Mag as they have done at least a few articles on type-pairing and they link to the resources and web-sites they mention in the articles.

I do not know the original source for [this cheat sheet on mixing typefaces](http://www.as8.it/handouts/mixing-typefaces_U&lc1992.pdf) and it has attained a high level of propagation on the internet.

[Heofler & Frere-Jones tips on the subject](http://www.typography.com/ask/recentTopic.php?path=head)

The [Typophile](http://typophile.com/) and [Typopedia](http://typedia.com/forum/) forums.

And the [Education section of FontShop](http://www.fontshop.com/education/)

Again these are not going to pair typefaces for you, but you can get some very helpful information on how to do it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never used it but [Typecast](http://typecast.com/) looks pretty good for this.. theres a video [here](https://typecast.com/customers/conde-nast/play) about it which is pretty interesting to watch.

Answer (score 0):

I like to take a look at http://fontsinuse.com/ every now and then, it's not specifically about pairing fonts but a showcase of fonts used in projects so obviously a lot of them are pairings. I think it's great not only to see the pairing but also the different dynamics, weights, how each font is used within the project.

There is a more humoristic approach at http://www.typeconnection.com/ which explores typographic "dating", asking you to come up with matches and then explaining why it works or doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at: https://www.fontpairings.com/ it has a nice researched approach to font pairing.